# How to convert handlebars to ejs

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, ejs

This is probably an easy question but I can't figure it out.

I want to change this handlebar code into ejs

```
  {{#if hasErrors}}
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
  {{#each messages}}
                <p>{{ this }}</p>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}
```

I tried but i'm getting syntax error

```
 <%= if (Errors) {%>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <%= each messages %>
 <p><%= this%></p>
 </div>
 <% }%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "hasError" variable is of type boolean, and your messages variable is an array of message strings;

```
<% if (hasErrors) {%>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <% messages.forEach(function(message){ %>
       <p><%= message %></p>
     <% });%>
 </div>
<% }%>
```